# Вывести скрипт в html

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код с помощью которого я вывожу в консоль 32 комбинации + и -;

for (let i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {

```
console.log(Array(5).fill(1).map((a, b) => '+-'[+!(i & a << b)]).join(''));}
```

Мне нужно вывести эти комбинации в html. Но при такой записи document.getElementById("kombo").innerHTML = Array(5).fill(1).map((a, b) => '+-'[+!(i & a << b)]).join(''); В html выводится только последняя комбинация. Подскажите, что не так?

Вот код html div id="kombo"; css #kombo {height: 100%;width: 100%;font-size: 50px;}

Answer (score 1):

Ди цикла

```
let result = '';
```

В цикле

```
result += Array(5).fill(1).map((a, b) => '+-'[+!(i & a << b)]).join(''));
```

За циклом

```
document.getElementById("kombo").innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: `textContent`, а не `innerHTML`.